# List of material properties for a Ray Tracer

Tags: raytracing

I wrote a Ray Tracer for an assignment this past semester and wanted to keep working on it. There were 5 kinds of materials (for objects) in the assignment and we were given their ambient, diffuse, specular, and shininess values. I'm having a hard time finding a list of these values to create new materials online (one that also included indices of refraction would be fantastic) and was wondering if anyone knew of a good resource for this.

This is the best one I have found so far but it doesn't have that many materials and the materials that have indices of refraction don't have the other values I mentioned above: http://www.nicoptere.net/dump/materials.html

I have never done refraction for a Ray Tracer (planning on learning it for fun), any general advice would be welcome.

Comment: I did find something with a number of common materials: http://globe3d.sourceforge.net/g3d_html/gl-materials__ads.htm

Comment: In your first link, the other material properties are given further down for most of the materials, except for 'clear' ones like diamond and water.

Comment: Also, if you have the index of refraction `eta` you can calculate the amount of reflected and refracted light: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fresnel_equations

Comment: You might want to look into physically based ray tracing.

Comment: @fluffels, thank you but I figured this out a long time ago (this was posted a year and a half ago). I just let the question stay because it appears when Googling "raytracing materials"

Answer (score 3):

Use other open source ray tracers as resource, e.g. [POV-Ray](http://www.povray.org/). You find the definition of materials in the [`distribution/include` Path](https://github.com/POV-Ray/povray/tree/master/distribution/include).

An example from `metals.inc` (put together):

```
#declare P_Brass1    = color rgb <0.30, 0.20, 0.10>;

#declare F_MetalA  =
finish {
    ambient 0.35
    brilliance 2
    diffuse 0.3
    metallic
    specular 0.80
    roughness 1/20
    reflection 0.1
}

#declare T_Brass_1A = texture { pigment { P_Brass1 } finish { F_MetalA  } }
```